# OpenACC: How to apply openacc pragma to "macro loops"

Tags: openacc

I defined these macros:

```
#define I_LOOP(g, i)     _ibeg = g->lbeg[IDIR]; _iend = g->lend[IDIR];  \
                      for (i = _ibeg; i <= _iend; i++)
#define J_LOOP(g, j)     _jbeg = g->lbeg[JDIR]; _jend = g->lend[JDIR];  \
                      for (j = _jbeg; i <= _jend; j++)
```

I have this loop I want to parallelize

```
  #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(2) 
  I_LOOP(g, i){
  J_LOOP(g, j){
    U0[j][i] = Uc[j][i];
  }}
```

but I get **error: this kind of pragma may not be used here**.

Is there a way I can parallelize this loop with the macros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, OpenACC `loop` requires the `for` loop to be *tightly nested* inside it, that is without the preceding `_ibeg`, `_iend` assignments.

Second, for this kind of `#define` usage, you may be able to cook something up with `_Pragma` (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html, etc.):

```
#define I_LOOP(g, i)     _ibeg = g->lbeg[IDIR]; _iend = g->lend[IDIR];  \
                      _Pragma("acc parallel loop private(_jbeg, _jend") \
                      for (i = _ibeg; i <= _iend; i++)
#define J_LOOP(g, j)     _jbeg = g->lbeg[JDIR]; _jend = g->lend[JDIR];  \
                      _Pragma(acc loop) \
                      for (j = _jbeg; j <= _jend; j++)
```

(Untested; you didn't provide stand-alone example.)

(Notice I also fixed `i <= _jend` typo.)

Possibly indirection via `#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)` might be useful:

```
#define DO_PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)

#define I_LOOP(g, i, pragma)     _ibeg = g->lbeg[IDIR]; _iend = g->lend[IDIR];  \
                      DO_PRAGMA(pragma) \
                      for (i = _ibeg; i <= _iend; i++)
#define J_LOOP(g, j, pragma)     _jbeg = g->lbeg[JDIR]; _jend = g->lend[JDIR];  \
                      DO_PRAGMA(pragma) \
                      for (j = _jbeg; j <= _jend; j++)
```

..., and then:

```
I_LOOP(g, i, "acc parallel loop private(_jbeg, _jend"){
J_LOOP(g, j, "acc loop"){
  U0[j][i] = Uc[j][i];
}}
```

Some more code restructuring would be necessary for using the `collapse` clause, which again requires the `for` loops to be *tightly nested*.